# How do I derive the unique object id for a Databricks Notebook based dashboard?

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-notebook

I'm looking to build an automated DevOps pipeline that manages deployment of Azure Databricks notebooks and notebook based dashboards to different environments, as well as distributing the unique URL of the dashboards to business users.  The unique URL contains a number of sub components as follows:

https://adb-***{workspace id}***.***{random number}***.azuredatabricks.net/?o=***{workspace id}***#notebook/**{notebook object id}**/dashboard/***{dashboard object id}***

The workspace id and random number are static for each work space deployment and therefore can be easily obtained for the url.

The notebook object id can be derived using the databricks cli from the following cli command:

```
databricks workspace ls --absolute --long --id /Users/someone@example.com
```

The final piece of the url is the dashboard object id.  It seems however that there is no way of deriving the dashboard object id from either the databricks cli or the rest api.

Is there currently a way of deriving the the dashboard id and the notebook id it is associated with?